# How to see + group a list of active tcp connections on a windows server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, tcp, network-monitoring

A client has asked me to take a look at their windows 2008 server because it is running extremely slow. The server is running behind the Windows Firewall (yes, i know) and I believe the application running on the server is being abused.

I can see an extremely high number of tcp connections to the application if I go into Resource Monitor and look at Network>TCP Connections. However I would like to group these by IP address so that I might be able to track down the person abusing the server.

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: You'd be better off starting with something like Process Explorer on the server and looking at the application from that tool.

Comment: I've downloaded Process Explorer, but as far as I can tell there is still no way of grouping TCP connections by IP Address. 

I can see the process of the application, click into it and go to the TCP/IP tab and it shows an enormous amount of connections - but still no way of grouping.

Comment: sorry, correct...I've used it with the lower view (hit Ctrl-D in ProcExp) but that only covers DLLs and Handles.  I can look in a bit for another solution.  You can potentially use "netstat -a -n >> output.csv" and then open in Excel and sort/filter.

Comment: I found a way to do it on linux:

netstat -antu | grep :80 | grep -v LISTEN | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c

But not even the netstat has the full set of those switches and grep/awk/cut/sort/uniq can't be used on Windows.

Comment: Try Get-Process in Powershell.  I'd have to figure out a script to group it by IP, but again you could export the columns to CSV and then open and group in excel.

Comment: I was just looking at Powershell as it goes. I found this command on another website: `netstat -b | select-string ".exe" | sort-object -unique` for grouping netstat results by the application name. I'm not sure if/how it can be applied to IP addresses though

Comment: Yeah, that won't work unless you already had an IP in mind to look at, but since it will be dynamic there...won't really work.

Comment: The TCP connections counter in Perfmon is the accumulated TCP connections since the server was started. This isn't an accurate reflection of the number of current TCP connections.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a 'counter' what I'm looking at. Its a list of Applications, IPs that are connected, the port number (both remote+local), packet loss, Latency. If I sort them by the remote port they are using I can see connections disappear and new ones take their place under the same port number.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the comments above have looked into netstat pretty thoroughly, which is a pretty promising route if you can get it going easily.

The other route is by monitoring the network traffic, either on the box itself or at the router/switch. Flow formats like NetFlow/IPFIX/J-flow/sFlow are all useful for getting summaries of communications between hosts, and are the usual method of determining who's making the most connections or using most of the bandwidth on a system. It's kind of like a phone bill for the network: you get the hosts, the ports, and the number of packets/bytes for each session. You can then pretty easily tally up who's doing what.

You'll need two things to make this work: a flow exporter (if you can't easily get flow from the switch/router there are probably a half dozen free Windows flow exporters you can run directly on the box; Google will turn them up pretty easily) and a flow collector (ditto) to receive the flow records and put them in a format you can use.

It's more work to do that than to use netstat, but I think the answer will be more definitive -- you'll get the number and timestamps of the accesses by IP address, and byte volumes, which ought to be more than enough to pick the right culprit(s).